# convert a date into numeric string

Tags: python

How can I convert a date into a numeric date?

For example, I want to convert `'06-Jun-2021'` to `'20210609'` and then turn it into a string i can use in a webpage eg. `baseball.theater/games/20210609` so that i can automate the process daily.

using datetime i've managed to do :

```
print (todays_date.year,todays_date.month,todays_date.day,sep="")
```

which can print the output i need (without the trailing 0's) but i cannot make this into a string which i can use.

obviously i am a COMPLETE newcomer to python, so  be gentle please.

Comment: For `'06-Jun-2021'` you meant `'20210606'` right?

Comment: yes, thats right, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `datetime.strptime` to turn a string into a `datetime` object, then `datetime.strftime` to reformat it into a different string.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> s = '06-Jun-2021'
>>> dt = datetime.strptime(s, '%d-%b-%Y')
>>> dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
'20210606
```

For the specific case of the current day, you can use `datetime.today`

```
>>> datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
'20210609'
```

To combine this into your final string you can use `str.format`

```
>>> 'baseball.theater/games/{}'.format(datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d'))
'baseball.theater/games/20210609'
```

Comment: thank you , hopefully i can work out the rest myself

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking time.strftime()
The function needs **time** module
`import time`
then you can either use a variable and display that time in a specific format.

```py
t = time.time()
print(time.strftime('%H%M%S', t) # print the time t in specific format
print(time.strftime('%H%M%S') # print present time in specific format
```

Here is a list of options from [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm)

- %a - abbreviated weekday name
- %A - full weekday name
- %b - abbreviated month name
- %B - full month name
- %c - preferred date and time representation
- %C - century number (the year divided by 100, range 00 to 99)
- %d - day of the month (01 to 31)
- %D - same as %m/%d/%y
- %e - day of the month (1 to 31)
- %g - like %G, but without the century
- %G - 4-digit year corresponding to the ISO week number (see %V).
- %h - same as %b
- %H - hour, using a 24-hour clock (00 to 23)
- %I - hour, using a 12-hour clock (01 to 12)
- %j - day of the year (001 to 366)
- %m - month (01 to 12)
- %M - minute
- %n - newline character
- %p - either am or pm according to the given time value
- %r - time in a.m. and p.m. notation
- %R - time in 24 hour notation
- %S - second
- %t - tab character
- %T - current time, equal to %H:%M:%S
- %u - weekday as a number (1 to 7), Monday=1. Warning: In Sun Solaris Sunday=1
- %U - week number of the current year, starting with the first Sunday as the first day of the first week
- %V - The ISO 8601 week number of the current year (01 to 53), where week 1 is the first week that has at least 4 days in the current year, and with Monday as the first day of the week
- %W - week number of the current year, starting with the first Monday as the first day of the first week
- %w - day of the week as a decimal, Sunday=0
- %x - preferred date representation without the time
- %X - preferred time representation without the date
- %y - year without a century (range 00 to 99)
- %Y - year including the century
- %Z or %z - time zone or name or abbreviation
- %% - a literal % character

Answer (score -1):

Here, just typecast it to str and use .replace() method

```
from datetime import date   # datetime is a built-in module

today = str(date.today())
string = today.replace("-", "")
print(string)
```

P.S Just providing an alternate method to strftime